# Add to array or object with INDEX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how can i generate array or object with own index?

in php i can:

```
$array = array();

foreach($users as $user){
   $array[$user] = $user;
}
```

and in jQuery?

```
var arr = new Array();
$('input').each(function(){
   arr[$(this).val()] = $(this).val();
})
```

i would like use JS Object for this, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
$('input').each(function(){
   obj[$(this).val()] = $(this).val();
});
```

It's basically this simple. After this, you can access them either by `obj[value]` or `obj.value`.

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr = {};
$('input').each(function(){
    ...
```

That's all you need. In JavaScript, arrays (`new Array()` or `[]`) have consecutive indexes while objects (`new Object()` or `{}`) have arbitrary properties.

Comment: `arr` may not be the best name for an object variable :P

Answer (score 2):

this is originally not possible via arrays in 
but there is a way through which u can achieve it with JS objects

```
var person = { country: 'Pakistan' };
```

now this is an object
U will see that both these statements gives same result.

```
alert( person.country );
alert( person['country'] );
```

Now this means actually it is object, but it also acts like array.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an object instead of an array:

```
var obj = {};
$('input').each(function() {
    obj[$(this).val()] = $(this).val();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an object instead of an array

```
var arr = {};
```